# Does "good deeds do away with misdeeds" imply that good and bad deeds cancel out?

Tags: tafseer, deeds, reward, surat-hud

This question relates to:

> And establish prayer at the two ends of the day and at the approach of the night. Indeed, **good deeds do away with misdeeds**. That is a reminder for those who remember.
>   <sub>[Qur'an 11:114](https://quran.com/11/114)</sub>

I'm wondering if this means:

1. good deeds and bad deeds cancel out, i.e., the reward for a good deed is lost if it is used to "do away with misdeeds", or
2. in addition to good deeds "doing away with misdeeds", they are rewarded (with the reward equal to if no bad deeds were committed).

**Question**: Does "good deeds do away with misdeeds" imply that good and bad deeds cancel out, or that there is still a reward for good deeds?

(Also related is *...a good deed will have ten times the like thereof ... an evil deed will not be recompensed except the like thereof...* [Qur'an 6:160](https://quran.com/6/160).)

Answer (score 1):

And establish prayer at the two ends of the day and at the approach of the night. Indeed, good deeds do away with misdeeds. That is a reminder for those who remember.

it is mean that good deeds do away with misdeeds and they are rewarded for the good deeds

وقال الإمام أحمد : حدثنا يونس وعفان قالا حدثنا حماد - يعني : ابن سلمة - عن علي بن زيد - قال عفان : أنبأنا علي بن زيد ، عن يوسف بن مهران ، عن ابن عباس; أن رجلا أتى عمر قال : امرأة جاءت تبايعه ، فأدخلتها الدولج ، فأصبت منها ما دون الجماع ، فقال : ويحك . لعلها مغيبة في سبيل الله ؟ قال : أجل . قال : فأت أبا بكر فاسأله قال : فأتاه فسأله ، فقال : لعلها مغيبة في سبيل الله ؟ فقال مثل قول عمر ، ثم أتى النبي - صلى الله عليه وسلم - فقال له مثل ذلك ، قال : " فلعلها مغيبة في سبيل الله " . ونزل القرآن : ( وأقم الصلاة طرفي النهار وزلفا من الليل إن الحسنات يذهبن السيئات ) إلى آخر الآية ، فقال : يا رسول الله ، ألي خاصة أم للناس عامة ؟ فضرب - يعني : عمر - صدره بيده وقال : لا ولا نعمة عين ، بل للناس عامة . فقال رسول الله ، صلى الله عليه وسلم : " صدق عمر " .

and the second
 a good deed will have ten times the like thereof ... an evil deed will not be recompensed except the like thereof.

it is about writing the goods deeds and the bad deeds 
when you do a good deed it written as 10 and doing away with misdeeds 
and when you do a bad deed  it just written as 1 bad deed

Answer (score 0):

Allah says in the Quran: “Establish Salah at both ends of the day, and in the early hours of the night. Surely, good deeds erase bad deeds. That is a reminder for the mindful.” [11:114]

This is good news for the believers who have sinned, that they have an opportunity through good deeds to wiper out their bad ones. And you already mentioned the verse: "He that doeth good shall have ten times as much to his credit: He that doeth evil shall only be recompensed according to his evil: no wrong shall be done unto (any of) them."  https://quran.com/4/142

In addition, the Prophet (pbuh) has said:

“Narrated Ibn Mas'ud: A man kissed a woman (unlawfully) and then went to the Prophet and informed him. Allah revealed: And offer prayers perfectly At the two ends of the day And in some hours of the night (i.e. the five compulsory prayers). Verily! good deeds remove (annul) the evil deeds (small sins) (11.114). The man asked Allah's Apostle, "Is it for me?" He said, "It is for all my followers." [Hadith – Bukhari, Book #10, Hadith #504]

“'Abdullah reported that a person came to Allah's Apostle (may peace be upon him) and said: Allah's Messenger, I sported with a woman in the outskirts of Medina, and I have committed an offence short of fornication. Here I am (before you), kindly deliver verdict about me which you deem fit. Umar said: Allah concealed your fault. You had better conceal it yourself also. Allah's Apostle (may peace be upon him), however, gave no reply to him. The man stood up and went away and Allah's Apostle (may peace be upon him) sent a person after him to call him and be recited this verse:" And observe prayer at the ends of the day and in the first hours of the night. Surely, good deeds take away evil deeds. That is a reminder for the mindful" (xi. 115). A person amongst the people said: Allah's Apostle, does it concern this man only? Thereupon he (the Holy Prophet) said: No, but the people at large.” [Hadith – Muslim, Book #037, Hadith #6658]

“Narrated Abu Ayyash: The Apostle of Allah (peace_be_upon_him) said: If anyone says in the morning: "There is no god but Allah alone Who has no partner; to Him belong the dominions, to Him praise is due, and He is Omnipotent," he will have a reward equivalent to that for setting free a slave from among the descendants of Isma'il. He will have ten good deeds recorded for him, ten evil deeds deducted from him, he will be advanced ten degrees, and will be guarded from the Devil till the evening. If he says them in the evening, he will have a similar recompense till the morning. The version of Hammad says: A man saw the Apostle of Allah (peace_be_upon_him) in a dream and said: Apostle of Allah! Abu Ayyash is relating such and such on your authority. He said: Abu Ayyash has spoken the truth.” [Hadith – Sunan Abudawud, Book #41, Hadith #5059]

May Allah guide us to that which is good.